# Functions and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that $F$, and $G$ are differentiable functions defined on $[a,b]$ such that $F′(x) = G′(x)$ for all $x ∈ [a, b]$. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, show that $F$ and $G$ differ by a constant. That is, show that there exists a $C ∈ R$ such that $F (x) − G(x) = C$.
I am unsure where to even begin this problem

Comment: Write down your version of the fundamental theorem of calculus. You should be able to form it into
$$F(x) = \int_{t_0}^t F'(t) dt = \int_{t_0}^t G'(t) dt$$
where $t_0$ is dependent on $F$

Comment: would it be true to say $\int_a^bF'(x)=\int_a^bG'(x)$. Then we have this is equal to $F(x)+C_f=G(x)+C_g$. Thus $F(x)-G(x)=C_g-C_f$ where $C_g-C_f$ is some constant c?

Comment: If we really want to use the Fundamental Theorem and nothing else, we may need that the Riemann integral of the derivative exists.

Comment: user72195: yes, that is correct; but justification for the first conclusion needs to be given unless stated in your theorem.
@AndréNicolas assuming "differentiable" means $F,G \in C^1[a,b]$ that holds.

Comment: How would I justify that then?

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of $F(x) - G(x) = \int_a^x F'(x)dx + C_1 - (\int_a^x G'(x)dx+C_2)=\int_a^x (F'(x)-G'(x))dx +(C_1-C_2) = 0 + C =C$

Conversely, if $F(x) - G(x) = C$, then $F'(x) - G'(x) = 0$.